# Upgrading from Python2.7.12 to Python 3.8.1 on macOS 10.15.2 Catalina in Wing IDE Shell

Tags: upgrade, python3, macos, tcl

There are many threads online about making this upgrade. However, most people say **not** to remove the old Python2 - this can mess up the macOS on your system. I've thus installed Python3.8.1 (I needed the tkinter module for a class, which comes pre-packaged per their site).

Unfortunately, my Wing IDE shell is still defaulting to Python2. One user online said this can be fixed via accessing the **Project Properties** menu in Wing - but it has since been removed in the newest version. Currently, if I go to Edit -> Configure Python... I can find the customizable path for the Python Executable, the Python Path, and the Initial Directory.

On my machine right now, Python3.8.1 is installed in Applications. There is also another folder I found: **/Library/Frameworks/PythonFramework/3.8**.

I have tried setting the Python Executable to these two locations - but no luck. The following is the error I receive:

> - Could not launch or inspect Python executable '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/Python'. It should be the name of a Python interpreter that is on your PATH (such as python, python3.4, python.exe) or the full path to the Python interpreter you wish to use.

If anyone has an idea on how to resolve this, it would be much appreciated as my school does not offer setup help on personal machines. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Unbelievable, I spent a week with my kind TA trying to solve this issue with no luck. I just got it to work. Here is what I did (hopefully it will work for you too):

1. Open up Wing IDE.
2. Go to *Edit* -> *Configure Python...*
3. Ensure that **Python Path**, **Environment**, and **Initial Directory** are untouched.
4. Change **Python Executable** at the top to *Custom*.
5. Click the **Browse** button.
6. Navigate to the following:

> **/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8**

7. Hit **OK** and restart your Wing IDE shell terminal command-line pane. (or the whole program altogether).

Upon startup, it should now show Python3.8.1  as your version. The python3.8 file in /bin/ did not appear as an executable file for me, or even one of note, it was only about 10 KB big. But it works, so hopefully someone else finds this if they ever come across the problem.